# Specialization of singleton parameters

Tags: haskell, ghc, specialization, coercion, singleton-type

I'm playing around with specialization of singletons:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

module Data.Test where

data SingBool (b :: Bool) where
  STrue :: SingBool 'True
  SFalse :: SingBool 'False

sing :: SingBool b -> Bool
sing SFalse = False
sing STrue  = True
{-# SPECIALIZE sing :: SingBool 'False -> Bool #-}
```

This specializes to something like the following:

```
singSFalse :: SingBool 'False -> Bool
singSFalse SFalse = False
```

I'd expect it to generate an RHS of `singSFalse _ = False` instead.

Is that coercion unpacked only to satisfy the type-checker or is there actual runtime overhead involved in that pattern match? I imagine that GHC does not discard the pattern match on the argument to account for `bottom`, in order not to increase laziness. But I want to be sure before I begin to model this through `Proxy` + a `SingI`-style type class.

Comment: I think your diagnosis is correct, but I should mention that last I heard the GHC documentation was kind of lying about `SPECIALIZE` and GADTs. That pragma (probably) has no effect, and if specialization happens its through constructor specialization.

Comment: Ah, that explains the warnings (something along the lines of 'SPECIALIZE has no effect here'). But even in my bigger use case, GHC specializes correctly beyond module boundaries without warnings, probably because there are also some type class dictionaries involved which I don't really specialize.
Edit: That might have to do with INLINABLE...

Comment: Anyway, I'm going with the type class solution https://github.com/sgraf812/pomaps/blob/ebfad35ca1864c6cb8f5921fb804cac26ca944f7/library/Data/POMap/Internal.hs#L207-L211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to mostly answer my own question: Knowing that `SingBool 'False` only has one inhabitant is not enough for GHC to get rid of the pattern match, because we could call the function like `singSFalse (error "matched")`, e.g. bottom is always another inhabitant.

So, specialization (e.g. inlining based on concrete `TypeApplication`s) does not really work well with singletons (turning those type applications into presumably constant value applications) in Haskell (lazy, non-total) w.r.t. zero cost abstractions.

However, by using a [`SingI`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.3.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:SingI)-style type class with a proxy (e.g. [`singByProxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.3.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#v:singByProxy)), we don't have the same problems:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash      #-}

module Data.Test where

import           GHC.Exts (Proxy#)

class SingIBool (b :: Bool) where
  sing :: Proxy# b -> Bool

instance SingIBool 'False where
  sing _ = False

instance SingIBool 'True where
  sing _ = True

refurbulate :: SingIBool b => Proxy# b -> Int
refurbulate p
  | sing p = 0
  | otherwise = 1
```

The specialization `refurbulate @(Proxy# 'False)` will not only be implemented as `const False`, also there will not be passed any `Proxy#` argument at the value level, so it's rather `coerce False :: Proxy# -> Bool`. Neat! However, I don't get to use singletons in the real world :(

---

To recap why singletons fail (to get optimized) and type classes work:

By specializing the type class instance, we get to know the RHS of `sing`, from which we can deduce totality.

By specializing the singleton, we get to know what value the parameter evaluates to, *if evaluation terminates*.

Knowing the canonical RHS of a type class method `x :: ()` is more informative than just knowing that a parameter `x :: ()` can only evaluate to one value in a non-total, lazy (e.g. Haskell's) setting.

Comment: The pattern match shouldn't be terribly expensive. It's really just `seq`; once the value is in WHNF, there's nothing else to do. And if you use a `SingI` class method that produces a `SingBool`, the application of `sing` to the result should be optimized properly, I believe. The problem with an overly class-based approach is that it gets messy when the type isn't statically known.

Comment: I'll probably benchmark this when the rest of the code is stable.